# How to stub/mock without coupling the test to the code under test with rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, rspec-mocks

Say there's a worker, whose job is to:

- find or create a record by a set of critaria;
- update an attribute of the record.

Here's a sample implementation:

```
class HardWorker
  include SidekiqWorker

  def perform(foo_id, bar_id)
    record = find_or_create(foo_id, bar_id)

    update_record(record)
  end

  private

  def find_or_create(foo_id, bar_id)
    MyRecord.find_or_create_by(foo_id: foo_id, bar_id: bar_id)
  end

  def update_record(record)
    result_of_complicated_calculations = ComplicatedService.new(record).call

    record.update(attribute: result_of_complicated_calculations)
  end
end
```

I want to test that:

- the worker creates the record if the record doesn't exist;
- the worker doesn't create a new record, but fetches the existing one if the record exists;
- in any case, the worker updates the record

One way to test the last would be to use `expect_any_instance_of`

```
expect_any_instance_of(MyRecord).to receive(:update)
```

The problem is that the usage of `expect/allow_any_instance_of` is [discouraged](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/working-with-legacy-code/any-instance):

> The rspec-mocks API is designed for individual object instances, but this feature operates on entire classes of objects. As a result there are some semantically confusing edge cases. For example in expect_any_instance_of(Widget).to receive(:name).twice it isn't clear whether each specific instance is expected to receive name twice, or if two receives total are expected. (It's the former.)
>
> Using this feature is often a design smell. It may be that your test is trying to do too much or that the object under test is too complex.
>
> It is the most complicated feature of rspec-mocks, and has historically received the most bug reports. (None of the core team actively use it, which doesn't help.)

The proper way would be to use an `instance_double`. So I would try:

```
record = instance_double('record')

expect(MyRecord).to receive(:find_or_create_by).and_return(record)

expect(record).to receive(:update!)
```

This is all nice and fine, however, what if I have this implementation:

```
MyRecord.includes(:foo, :bar).find_or_create_by(foo_id: foo_id, bar_id: bar_id)
```

Now, `expect(MyRecord).to receive(:find_or_create_by).and_return(record)`, won't work, because
actually the object, that receives `find_or_create_by` is an instance of 
`MyRecord::ActiveRecord_Relation`.

So now I need to stub the call to `includes`:

```
record = instance_double('record')

relation = instance_double('acitve_record_relation')

expect(MyRecord).to receive(:includes).and_return(relation)

expect(relation).to receive(:find_or_create_by).and_return(record)
```

Also, say I call my service like so:

```
ComplicatedService.new(record.baz, record.dam).call
```

Now, I'll get errors that unexpected messages `baz` and `dam` were received by `record`. 
Now I need to either `expect/allow` those messages or use a 
[Null object double](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-6/docs/basics/null-object-doubles).

So after all this, I end up with a test, which super tightly reflects the implementation 
of the methods/classes that are under test. Why should I care, that some additional 
records are eager-loaded via `includes`, while fetching the record? Why should I care, 
that before calling `update`, I also call some methods (`baz`, `dam`) on the record?

Is this a limitation of the rspec-mocks framework / the philosophy of the framework or am 
I using it wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I modified the initial version a bit to make it easier to test:

```
class HardWorker
  include SidekiqWorker

  def perform(foo_id, bar_id)
    record = find_or_create(foo_id, bar_id)

    update_record(record)
  end

  private

  def find_or_create(foo_id, bar_id)
    MyRecord.find_or_create_by(foo_id: foo_id, bar_id: bar_id)
  end

  def update_record(record)
    # change for easier stubbing
    result_of_complicated_calculations = ComplicatedService.call(record)

    record.update(attribute: result_of_complicated_calculations)
  end
end
```

The way, I would test this is:

```
describe HardWorker do
  before do
    # stub once and return an "unique value"
    allow(ComplicatedService).to receive(:call).with(instance_of(HardWorker)).and_return :result_from_service
  end

  # then do two simple tests
  it 'creates new record when one does not exists' do
    allow(ComplicatedService).to receive(:call).with(instance_of(HardWorker)).and_return :result_from_service
    HardWorker.call(1, 2)

    record = MyRecord.find(foo_id: 1, bar_id: 2)

    expect(record.attribute).to eq :result_from_service
  end

  it 'updates existing record when one exists' do
    record = create foo_id: 1, bar_id: 2

    HardWorker.call(record.foo_id, record.bar_id)

    record.reload

    expect(record.attribute).to eq :result_from_service
  end
end
```